# How to http.post a complex object (or List of objects) from Angular 10+ to .NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular12

I want to http.post a complex object (or List of objects) from Angular 10+ to .NET Core 6. Can someone guide me please?

Frontend:

```
postFnc(object: any, id: any): void{

var body = {
"objectKey":obj,
"id":id};

const headers = {
'Content-Type':'application/json'};

return this.http.post\<any\>(url,body,{headers});

}
```

Backend:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("url")]
public returntype FnName([FromBody] List<object> data)
{
    // DoSomething
}
```

I tried `JsonObject`, but I am not able to convert the `JsonObject` to a C# class type. Any suggestion that works is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your Angular code, you seems to post the request body with object instead of array. And there is extra comma in the line `this.http.post()`. While would suggest creating a model class to get the property value easily.

Comment: Create a proper DTO type in C# and use that instead of `object`. It's ASP.NET Core's job to deserialize the JSON payload to a `List<MyDTO>`

Comment: The list type should be `JsonArray`.

Comment: @YongShun: Please ignore the typo. That was only an error while posting this question.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

Frontend:

```
export class ComplexObjectDTO {
  innerObject: InnerClassDTO
}

...

 postFunction(object: ComplexObjectDTO): Observable<any>{
   const headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
   };

   return this.http.post<any>(url,object,headers);
}
```

To do that, you must create a class and I suggest you to create it in another file (you could use DTO pattern). The same class must be also added in your Backend (you could also use dynamic, but I don't suggest you to do so)

Backend:

```
public class ComplexObjectDTO
{
    public InnerClassDTO innerObject{ get; set; }
}

...

[HttpPost]
[Route("url")]
public returntype FnName([FromBody] ComplexObjectDTO data)
{
    // DoSomething
}
```

Moreover, according to RestAPI rules, if you're using POST the API call should return a HTTP 201 status code and include a Location header that points to the URL of the new resource.

Comment: Another note: make sure the model (`ObjectClass`) class defines properties, and not fields. Or else it won't work

Comment: What if my ObjectClass is a complex class?

Comment: What do you mean with complex class? A class with other classes inside? In that case you can do the same thing, but pay attention to circular references (another reason to adopt DTO pattern)

Comment: Yes, you're right a complex class with another class inside. Can you please post an example with angular and C# code and DTO definition?

Answer (score 0):

From Angular you not pass to your API a "List of object", or you pass to your Angular an object or an array of object

For me, you should pass an typed object/array. So you define in your .NET a class

```
public class RequestData{
   public int PropInt {get;set;}
   public DateTime PropDate {get;set;} //<--see that from angular you pass a 
                                       //string in the way "yyyy-MM-dd"
   public string PropString {get;set;}
   ...
   public AnotherClass[] PropArray {get;set;}
}

//And your functions

public async Task<object> DoSomething([FromBody] RequestData request){}

//or 
public async Task<object> DoSomething([FromBody] RequestData[] request){}
```

Yes it's a bit weird define an interface in Angular and again a class in .NET

NOTE: Angular, by defect send the data in JSON format, so avoid write the header or use JSON.stringfy or another thing

**Update*, So, we can create a service

```
export interface dataInterface
{
  propInt:int;
  propDate:any;
  propString:string;
  anotherClass:propArray[];
}
export interface propArray{
  one:string;
}
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  url="myurl.mydominio.com"
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

}
saveData(obj:dataInterface)
{
   obj.propDate=this.parseDate(obj.propDate)
   return this.httpClient.post(this.url,obj)
}

parseDate(data:any)
{
   return data.getFullYear()+'-'+
          ('00'+(data.getMonth()+1)).splice(-2)+'-'+
          ('00'+data.getDate).splice(-2)
}
```

And in our component

```
  constructor(private dataService:DataService) { }
  submit()
  {
       const obj={
         propInt:1,
         propDate:new Date(),
         propString:'fool'
         anotherClass:[{one:'one'},{one:'two'}]
         
       }
       this.dataService.saveData(obj).subscribe(res=>{
           console.log(res)
       })
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share an example on how to post this from angular?

Comment: @Kuzhapuvan it's only crete an object and use it. NOTE: To know about httpClient read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your body like below ,it will work. its a `JsonArray` type.

```
      var body=[
         {
            "objectKey":obj,
            "id":id
         },
         {
            "objectKey":obj,
            "id":id
         }]
```

Test
[image]